# Retornar Estatisticas Post Página Facebook

Tags: facebook

Usando a api v2.9.

```
 include('controller/facebook/init.php');


 try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get(
    '/POST_ID/likes',
    'ACCESS_TOKEN',
    'summary=total_count'
  );
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
$graphEdge = $response->getGraphEdge();
print_r($graphEdge);
```

O objetivo em questão é obter o total de likes do post, também acredito que trocando o termo 'likes' por `shares` ou `comments` será retornado os dados correspondentes ao post.

O print retornado é o da imagem, mas, não é retornado o total.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]